# How to retrive the text from text field (Password) after enter the text

Tags: java, selenium

Step-1 Enter the text into the text field(Password)
Step-2 After enter the text into the text field ,retrive the text from text field

This is for Selenium by using java

```
***WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("usrPwd"));
Password.sendKeys("Future1234");
String Text = driver.findElement(By.id("usrPwd")).getAttribute("Value");
System.out.println(Text);***
```

the actual output is null in console,but the expected output is "Future1234"

Comment: IDK if Selenium is case sensitive, but the attribute you are referring to is "value" and not "Value"

Comment: HTML elements won't change its value dynamically based on what happens in the UI. 

So entering text into a password field won't change its value when viewing it via Chrome Developer tool for example which is why it's null because the field was empty when loaded.

Comment: @Smutje HTML attributes are generally not case sensitive so it wouldn't matter if it was 'value' or 'Value'

Comment: not sure why you'd want to do this, but you can execute javascript to get the field contents.

Comment: its working fine now ya its case sensitive "value" and not "Value" @Smutje

Comment: thanku for suggestion @StephenK

Comment: @pcalkins i think is easy way to get the text!

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to find the element once again, typing keys won't cause [StaleElementReferenceException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html). Alternatively to be on the safe side you can consider implementing [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model), this way you will not have to find elements or wait for them, it will be handled by [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)
2. `value` attribute of the [password input type](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_password_value.asp) should be lowercase

   [image]

Comment: Thanku for give me the new solution